# Golang mgo Finding

Tags: database, mongodb, go, struct, mgo

I try to find my user in MongoDB but when I run this code :

```
type Person struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`//`json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    username string `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    score string `json:"score" bson:"score"`
    level string `json:"level" bson:"level"`
}

result := Person{}
var id = "5b8a45912ed6f24d945bee38"
err = c.Find(bson.M{"_id":bson.ObjectIdHex(id)}).Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "score":1, "level": 1}).One(&result)

fmt.Println(result)
```

Just It show me :

`{ObjectIdHex("5b8a45912ed6f24d945bee38")   }`

And don't return other value!

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Export your fields!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go nested object with mgo adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479595/go-nested-object-with-mgo-adapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you should use the capital letter in first of struct names!
And also you don't need

```
 Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "score":1, "level": 1})
```

You can write :

```
err = c.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(id)).One(&result)
```

Good Luck :))

Comment: "+1"
Thank you soo much

Comment: Do you use Go for back-end?

Comment: You're welcome!
Yes, I use GO! For my work is BEST! :))

Answer (score 4):

You have to export all struct fields subject to marshaling / unmarshaling, so change their name to start with capital letter:

```
type Person struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`//`json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Username string        `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Score    string        `json:"score" bson:"score"`
    Level    string        `json:"level" bson:"level"`
}
```

Also note that to find a document by its ID, you may use [`Collection.FindId()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.FindId):

```
err = c.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(id)).
    Select(bson.M{"username": 1, "score":1, "level": 1}).One(&result)
```

Comment: Can we talk on mail or discord?! Pleas? Can you give your id?!

Comment: @JustinJohnson Talk about what? Ask here.